# ionic2 service data rention

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have the following service class, its been set as singleton in providers etc.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Geolocation } from 'ionic-native';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {
private appData: any;
constructor(private http: Http) {
    console.log("service constructor called");
    this.loadAppData();
}

loadAppData() {
    let url = `/api/b502daab-2c7b-4cea-a00e-dc5aa6b58196`;
    this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        this.appData = data;
        console.log(this.appData);
    });
    console.log(this.appData);
}
getAppData()
{
    return this.appData;
}

}
```

The console.log(this.appData) inside the subscribe outputs an object as it should the one after outputs undefined, shouldnt it be set by then? to make the matters worse.

I am calling the loadappdata on constructor and in my pages i want to get the object by calling

```
export class HomePage {

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public testService: TestService) {
console.log(testService.getAppData());
};


}
```

but getAppData is always undefined,

I am trying to have a service retain an object so my pages can get data from this as they need. I was under the impression that thats how one should utilize service to  share data across pages

Answer (score 0):

You are facing those issues because of the asyncronous ajax request of the http.get call. The programm order in this.loadAppData function is as follows:
First you do the ajax request this.http.get

Next you console.log outside the subscribe

Once the response of the get request receives the response the arrow function of subscribe will be called and you console.log again.

The solution is to return the http.get Observable from the service and subscribe to it in your component.

```
@Injectable()
export class TestService {
constructor(private http: Http) {}

loadAppData() {
    let url = `/api/b502daab-2c7b-4cea-a00e-dc5aa6b58196`;
    return this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
}


export class HomePage {
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public testService: TestService) {
        this.testService.loadAppData().subscribe(data => {
            this.appData = data;
        });
    };
}
```

To cache your data you could return a Promise that resolves to locally cached data or if not available requests and returns. For example:

```
@Injectable()
export class TestService {

    public data: any;

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    loadAppData() {

        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            if (this.data) {
                return resolve(this.data);
            } else {
                let url = `/api/b502daab-2c7b-4cea-a00e-dc5aa6b58196`;
                return this.http.get(url)
                    .map(res => res.json())
                    .subscribe(data => {
                        this.data = data;
                        return resolve(data);
                    });
            }
       });
}
```

Comment: but if i make multiple calls to loadAppData from multiple pages wont that call the url multiple times? I am trying to call loadAppData once and have the result of that be used without having to call the service over and over

Comment: I added some code. Disadvantage is you don't have any control over when to reload the data again.
What you could do instead is in your app.component, to load the data as you do it in the HomePage of my first example and in the subscribe success function assign the data to a TestService member variable that you access in every page and then assign the rootPage.

Answer (score 0):

1 - You can use ngrx store https://github.com/ngrx/store - to store the service results and each page will retrieve the information from the store.

2- Use [ReplaySubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/replaysubject.md) -

In your service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Geolocation } from 'ionic-native';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {
private appData: any;
constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.userSubject = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);
this.loadAppData().subscribe(resp => {console.log(resp)});
}

loadAppData():observable<any> {
    let url = `/api/b502daab-2c7b-4cea-a00e-dc5aa6b58196`;
    this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json()).map(data => {
      this.userSubject.next(data);
      return data;
    });
    console.log(this.appData);
}

get appData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.userSubject.asObservable();
  }
```

In your home page:

```
export class HomePage {

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public testService: TestService) {
console.log(testService.getAppData());
};

ngOninit() {
this.appData.subscribe(resp => {
 console.log(resp)
});
```

}

in Your Profile page:

```
export class ProfilePage {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public testService: TestService) {
    console.log(testService.getAppData());
    };

    ngOninit() {
    this.appData.subscribe(resp => {
     console.log(resp)
    });
}
```

Comment: cant i just store the object i get back in a global than having to use a store? seems not efficient to have to store and retrieve moments later.